# Unity 5.0 Application Quit in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Recently I upgrade my android game from Unity 4.6 to 5.0. It runs no problem in editor. When I put it in any android mobile, it will show the following error message:

E/Unity   (23691): RenderTexture warning: Destroying active render texture. Switching to main context.

How can I destroy all active render texture? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to cleanup the render texture in a `OnDestroy`: set `RenderTexture.active` and perhaps all of your `Camera.targetTexture` to null. If that doesn't work, there is  a `Release()` method or a static `Object.Destroy(theRenderTexture)`.

Also consider using temporary RenderTextures.

Please post which one worked.

Comment: Is it possible to write an universal code to locate all camera objects and clean up those texture?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make changes to the Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml.

Remove the following:

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**But** copy the entire intent-filter section into the activity called UnityPlayerActivity to look like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This solution worked for me and was taken from theprisoner6 in this thread:

[Mobile game restarts when using Application.Quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888679/mobile-game-restarts-when-using-application-quit)

Comment: I tried your approach but the warning still shows in adb log.